# Prefixquery and sort in lucene

Tags: autocomplete, lucene.net

I use lucene.net. I indexed documents with two fields. First field is name and second field is count. 
I use this index for autocomplete. I need find 10 names by prefix and the higest count.
How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm for Autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190403/algorithm-for-autocomplete)

Comment: He is looking for a lucene specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("countfieldname", SortField.INT,true));
PrefixQuery pq = new PrefixQuery(new Term("namefieldname", "prefix"));
indexSearcher.Search(pq,null,10, sort);
```

Comment: I tried it  , but this doesn't work . It works , but without sort .

Comment: do you get an exception, if yes which one? note that you cannot sort on tokenized fields

Comment: No, I get answer without exception. I get results, but unsorted . I don't use tokenized.